# grunt-contrib-cssmin combine doesn't combine?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

i've written a simple Gruntfile.js to combine 2 css files into one using grunt-contrib-cssmin.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'public/css/test.css': ['public/css/**/*.css']
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

When I run `grunt cssmin --verbose` the output ends with

```
Running "cssmin:combine" (cssmin) task
Verifying property cssmin.combine exists in config...OK
Files: public/css/cart.css, public/css/main.css -> public/css/test.css
Options: report="min"
Reading public/css/cart.css...OK
Reading public/css/main.css...OK
```

After that the terminal hangs and my node process keeps using 100% of the cpu but does not produce an output file.

Extra info: i'm working on an Express + nodejs project.

System Info
mac osx 10.9.5

Output of these commands:

`grunt --version && node --version && npm --version`

grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
v0.10.32
1.4.28

Comment: Can you package your whole project and upload it on Dropbox or something? I am going to try this on my side because I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert i've reduced te project and put it in this [zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaAZjEgJ6kiNUhVRFpwYk96d3M/view?usp=sharing). When i run `grunt --verbose`i can see he reeds the 2 css files but doesn't combine them